# What does the operator | mean in ml

Tags: function, sml, smlnj, ml, function-signature

I am writing some code in SML and I tackled this function signature

(bool | int) -> (int * int)

I wondered what's the meaning of this signature

Comment: And what was the function whose signature was represented this way? This signature makes no sense to me. The pipe operator is used in case statements, and in datatype declarations, but I have not seen it in a function signature before.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: AFAICT this is not a legal Standard ML type signature.